# How to make an android device act like a ble advertiser or peripheral?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any react native package that can run android as a BLE advertiser or perihperals?

I already use a 'react-native-ble-manager', 'react-native-ble-peripheral', and 'react-native-ble-plx'. But, it seems that they can't do what i want. They can only scan ble devices, not make my phone as a ble device.

Comment: I might not have understood your requirements correctly, but it seems like react-native-ble-peripheral is exactly what you want. Can you tell us what didn't work for you exactly?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan. I think the package itself isn't working. When i'm about to import the package, it says "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-ble-peripheral'. '/Users/husein/Documents/coding/blePeripheral/node_modules/react-native-ble-peripheral/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-ble-peripheral` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-ble-peripheral';`ts(7016)". Idk why this is happen, even though i have installed it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. have you tried asking for that problem on their [github page](https://github.com/himelbrand/react-native-ble-peripheral)?